# Mysql return key based on count and interval

Tags: mysql, count, intervals

I'm trying to write a query to find an eligble key. The criteria for an key being eligble is that it must not have been used 10 times within 24 hrs.

Every time a key has been used, a record is saved in my table api_history.

Can anyone please teach me how to do it correctly? Currently I'm getting an empty key returned, as no records exists in the api_history. (Then it should just have returned the first giving key).

Thanks in advance!

Query:

```
SELECT ak.key 
FROM api_history ah 
  INNER JOIN api_keys ak ON ah.key_id = ah.id 
WHERE ah.used_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
HAVING COUNT(ah.id) < 10 LIMIT 0,1
```

Tables:

**api_keys**

- id (int)
- key (string)

**api_history**

- id (int)
- key_id (int)
- used_at (datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will it work for you?

```
SELECT ak.key, COUNT(ah.id) as num_usage_24hrs 
FROM api_keys  ak
LEFT JOIN api_history ah ON (ah.key_id = ak.id 
    AND ah.used_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) )    
GROUP BY ak.key
HAVING COUNT(ah.id) < 10
```

** you probably don't need `COUNT(ah.id) as num_usage_24hrs` in `select`, I output it just for debugging.

**UPDATED**  (It should be `ah.key_id = ak.id`, not `ah.key_id = ah.id` )

Comment: This still returns the first key, even though there's now 10 rows in the api_history table with the used_at date 2012-08-03 00:00:00

Comment: Fixing. I pasted query from your question and didn't realize that join condition is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Try that :

```
SELECT ak.key 
FROM api_keys ak
  LEFT JOIN api_history ah 
    ON  ah.key_id = ak.id 
    AND ah.used_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY ak.key
HAVING COUNT(ah.id) < 10 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY ak.key HAVING COUNT(ah.id) < 10 LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: `ah.key_id = ah.id ` is incorrect join condition. It's not gonna work as expected.

Comment: Sorry.. It's : ah.key_id = ak.id

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the max key in the api_keys table if I understand correctly.  So maybe you could do something like this?

```
SELECT max(ak.key) 
FROM api_keys ak
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM api_history ah 
WHERE ah.key_id = ak.id AND ah.used_at > DATE_SUB(now(), ITERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY ah.key_id
HAVING COUNT(ah.id)<10)
```